# Use promise inside resolved promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get one array based on the result of another array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.data.ftListes.length; i++) {
    //Get the name of the task related to the timesheet
    tachesPromises.push(Tache.getTachebyId(result.data.ftListes[i].tacheid));
    // I tried to get the project here but it didn't work   
}

//resolve promises
$q.all(tachesPromises).then(function(taches) {
    taches.forEach(function(el) {
        tasks.push(el.data.tachelistes);
        projetsPromises.push(Projet.getProjetbyId(el.data.tachelistes.projet_id));
    });
});

$q.all(projetsPromises).then(function(p) {
    p.forEach(function(el) {
        projet.push(el.data.projetsListe);
    });
});
```

It seems that my get request is working but I don't see the result

Comment: When asking for help, please indent and format your code consistently and reasonably. Tushar's done it for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `$q.all` on `projetsPromises` before it has anything in it. You need to do that **inside** the handler on your previous `$q.all` call.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.data.ftListes.length; i++) {
    //Get the name of the task related to the timesheet
    tachesPromises.push(Tache.getTachebyId(result.data.ftListes[i].tacheid));
    // I tried to get the project here but it didn't work   
}

//resolve promises
$q.all(tachesPromises).then(function(taches) {
    taches.forEach(function(el) {
        tasks.push(el.data.tachelistes);
        projetsPromises.push(Projet.getProjetbyId(el.data.tachelistes.projet_id));
    });
    $q.all(projetsPromises).then(function(p) {  // Moved
        p.forEach(function(el) {                //
            projet.push(el.data.projetsListe);  //
        });                                     //
    });                                         //
});
```

---

Just for what it's worth, your `for` loop at the outset is what `Array#map` was designed to do:

```
tachesPromises = result.data.ftListes.map(function(e) {
    return Tache.getTachebyId(e.tacheid);
});
```

or with an ES2015+ arrow function:

```
tachesPromises = result.data.ftListes.map(e => Tache.getTachebyId(e.tacheid));
```

...assuming, of course, that `result.data.ftListes` is an array. :-)